# What does 'Pdte. Comenzar' mean?

Tags: abreviaturas

I am in an IT project and in one of the Excelsheets with status of the documents to be delivered there is 'Pdte. Comenzar' which I have no idea how to translate.

I checked online and the abbreviation Pdte. refers usually to Presidente which does not make sense in this case. The document is written in Spain Spanish.

What does it stand for then? I assume it is pendiente. Am I right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## English

You are right.

I am from Spain and is pretty common to use `Pdte` as an abbreviation of `Pendiente`. So `Pdte. Comenzar` would mean `Pendiente de Comenzar`.

You also are right about Presidente, in fact, RAE, in the [appendix number two](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice2.html) lists `Pdte` (or `Pdta`, in the femenine form) as the abbreviation of `Presidente/a`

## Español

Estás en lo cierto.

Soy de España y aquí es muy común usar `Pdte` como abreviatura de `Pendiente`. Así que `Pdte. Comenzar` significaría `Pendiente de Comenzar`.

También estás en lo cierto sobre Presidente, de hecho, la RAE, en su [apéndice número dos](http://buscon.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice2.html) lista `Pdte` (o `Pdta`, en su forma femenina) como abreviatura de `Presidente/a`.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por la respuesta tan rápida!